# Aligning navigation bar logo and links in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried numerous methods but I cannot get the logo and the `li` elements to align properly in the header.I also cannot seem to increase the height of the header.I've tried different methods but no success.

Basically what I want is first to increase the header's size (I have a `navbar-static-top` header) and make the logo and the ul elements appear properly.However I have no ideea how I can do that.I also want to keep the logo's current dimensions.It does work with the current header if I resize the logo but that's not what I am after.

Bootply
  [[1]: http://www.bootply.com/BTSfbDudpZ](http://www.bootply.com/BTSfbDudpZ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following css

```
.navbar-brand {
  height: auto;
}

.navbar-nav{
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: It worked, now I just have to figure out how to pull to right the li elements and to left the logo